# ngFor not accessing the list

Tags: angular, treeview, ngfor

Similar to another *ngFor, but solution didn't work.  This is a skeleton for a treeview. The home module html calls the tree-view component.
HOME html

```
<div>
  home component before htr-tree-view
  <htr-tree-view></htr-tree-view>
  home component after htr-tree-view
</div>
```

Home component important parts: the constructor and ngOnInit

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TreeNode} from '../tree-view/TreeNode';
import {TreeViewComponent} from '../tree-view/tree-view.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'cs-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private tree: TreeViewComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const firstNode = new TreeNode('0', 'All Projects', null);
    this.tree.addNode(null, firstNode);
  }
}
```

TreeNode is a single ts file of the class:

```
 export class TreeNode {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   canEdit: boolean;
   canDelete: boolean;
   canAdd: boolean;
   data: any;
   children: Array<TreeNode>;

   constructor(Id: string, Name: string, Data: any) {
     this.id = Id;
     this.name = Name;
     this.data = Data;
     this.canEdit = true;
     this.canDelete = true;
     this.canAdd = true;
     this.children = new Array<TreeNode>();
   }
 }
```

Which brings us to the very simple tree-view component.  HOME calls it during its ngOnInit to addNode a new node.  Since the tree is empty, it pushes the node onto this.nodes.  I've checked this.nodes content here and in the subsequent zone.run (which I had hoped would refresh the screen), and the TreeNode is present in the list.

Tree-View Component:

```
 import {Component, NgZone, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
 import {TreeNode} from './TreeNode';
 import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

 @Component({
   selector: 'htr-tree-view',
   templateUrl: './tree-view.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./tree-view.component.scss']
 })
 export class TreeViewComponent implements OnInit {
   nodes: Array<TreeNode>;

   constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
     this.nodes = new Array<TreeNode>();
   }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

   addNode(Parent: TreeNode, NewNode: TreeNode) {
     if (Parent !== null) {
       Parent.children.push(NewNode);
     } else {
       this.nodes.push(NewNode);  <-- nodes has the new treenode here
     }
     this.zone.run(
       () => { console.log('refreshed');
                  console.log(this.nodes.length); <-- length is 1 here
       }
     );
   }
 }
```

TreeView HTML

```
 <div>
   tree-view.component.html start
   <table>
     <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let nxt of nodes">
       <td>N{{nxt.name}}</td>
       <td>I{{nxt.id}}</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
   tree-view.component.html end
 </div>
```

And the output to the browser is: (drum roll)

```
 home component before htr-tree-view
 tree-view.component.html start
 tree-view.component.html end
 home component after htr-tree-view
```

I'm sure I will be embarrassed at my oversight, but thank you in advance for your help.
Yogi

Comment: Further investigation: it seems though the Nodes list is being updated at runtime, the CHANGE is not causing Angular to see the list update.

Comment: SOLVED:  It was in fact my lack of understanding of how change management works in Angular 2+.  The solution then was to have the nodeTree defined in HOME component and the TreeView component to receive it (and any updates) via @Input.  This, among other things, will trigger the change detection.
:-)